# Accessing a list of checkboxes in a parent component to take action on checked elements

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am struggling with some functionality.  I have a component called ObjectTable that basically standardizes a b-table with data passed to it after a call to an RestAPI.

In the parent component:

```
<ObjectTable :source="source" :table_data="connectors_data" :display_fields="display_fields"/>
```

The table adds a v-slot that creates a checkbox:

```
  <template v-slot:cell(selects) = "row">
    <b-form-group>
      <b-form-checkbox id="row.item.id" @change="selectItem($event, row.item.id)" ></b-form-checkbox>
    </b-form-group>
  </template>
```

I need to find a way to understand what row ID's are checked in the parent component.  Since its a list of items, how can I emit an event when each is checked to store in the parent component?  Or can I specifically call something in the child component from a parent method (method is called when a button is pressed in the parent)?

Thank you for your help.

BCBB

Comment: Vue 2 or Vue 3?

Comment: Did you try using `$emit`?

Comment: Vue 2.  

I am not sure HOW to use $emit in this instance, the data is a list from an AJAX call that is passed to the table, the table is a b-table that adds a checkbox for each element in the list.  What do I tie $emit to?  My end goal here is to collect checked items to do an action - in this specific case, I want to set toggle a boolean field in the backend django model.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I got this working the way I wanted it.  I tied the component to a custom event called selectItem:

```
<ObjectTable :source="source" :table_data="connectors_data" :display_fields="display_fields" @selectItem="selectItem"/>
```

Then in the child component I tied an @change event to a method in the child component:

```
  <b-form-checkbox id="row.item.id" @change="selectItem($event, row.item.id)" >
```

Then in the method in the child I call emit to the tied in method in the parent, passing true or false based on the event to determine whether or not the item needs to be added to the list in the parent or removed.

```
  selectItem: function(e,i) {
    if (e) {
      this.$emit("selectItem", i, true)
    } else {
      this.$emit("selectItem", i, false)
    }
  },
```

In the parent, the method then either adds to the list or doesn't and when the button is clicked, it processes the select_items in the parent.

```
selectItem(item, add) {
      if (add) {
        this.select_items.push(item)
      } else {
        var ind = this.select_items.indexOf(item)
        this.select_items.splice(ind, 1)
      }
    }
```

BCBB